# Reverse DNS lookup doesn't match hostname

Tags: reverse-dns

There's a service on our local intranet that depends on the hostname mapping to the ip address, it is failing for a centos host inside of a virtual machine. I have set the virtual network adapter as bridged.

```
➜ ~ dig +short nikhil-vm
172.27.12.134 
➜ ~ dig +short -x 172.27.12.134 
ubuntu-server.xyz.com
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a PTR record to your intranet's DNS server(s) specifying the desired hostname for that IP address.

For instance, for a BIND zone `12.27.172.in-addr.arpa`:

```
134     IN      PTR     nikhil-vm.intranet.invalid.
```